# Which DLL do I need to reference for an LDAP COM object?

Tags: com, ldap

I know it's a bit old school, but I have to translate an LDAP function written in VB (Visual Basic not .net). And using managed code I can't produce the same result.

To solve the problem quickly I would like to use COM (Component Object Model) exactly as the Visual Basic function is doing like this:

```
set dso=GetObject("LDAP:")
```

I'm completely out of practice with COM, what DLL would I need to include as a reference to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Marshal.GetActiveObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx) is the equivalent to the VB GetObject call you are used to using.

This will return you the object, you then need to either:

1. Reference an interop assembly with the type definitions for your LDAP object
2. Make the calls to the object using reflection invoke
3. Use the [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword in C# 4.0 to make the calls to the object using a late bound mechanism, similar to what VB did

I recommend using option 3 if you are using .Net 4.0

Comment: Do you know the exact dll name and location?

Comment: I believe it's Activeds.dll, but I guess it could be any of:  Adsldp.dll, Adsldpc.dll, Adsmsext.dll, or Activeds.dll.